# Forecasting with AR model and differenced time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I want to n-step ahead forecast a time series with the AR(4) model and a first order differenced time series. Now my question is, if I get the concept right. Im assuming, I have to do the following equations but I am not sure

The model itself:

X(t)-X(t-1)=a(1)*(X(t-1)-X(t-2))+...+a(4)*(X(t-4)-X(t-5))

=> X(t)=X(t-1)+a(1)*(X(t-1)-X(t-2))+...+a(4)*(X(t-4)-X(t-5))

First forecast:

X(t+1)-X(t)=a(1)*(X(t)-X(t-1))+...+a(4)*(X(t-3)-X(t-4))

=> X(t+1)=X(t)+a(1)*(X(t)-X(t-1))+...+a(4)*(X(t-3)-X(t-4))

Second forecast:

X(t+2)-X(t+1)=a(1)*(X(t+1)-X(t))+...+a(4)*(X(t-2)-X(t-3))

=> X(t+2)=X(t+1)+a(1)*(X(t+1)-X(t))+...+a(4)*(X(t-2)-X(t-3))

and so on.

Am i right with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is all completely correct. Of course, if you need a value you don't know yet, you will need to feed in the already-forecasted values recursively.

For instance, assume that you already know $X_1, \dots, X_t$ and wish to forecast $\hat{X}_{t+1}, \hat{X}_{t+2}, \dots$. Your formula for $\hat{X}_{t+2}$ involves $X_{t+1}$, which you don't know yet, so you just plug in the forecast $\hat{X}_{t+1}$ which you calculated at the previous step.

In working with differenced series, it is often easier to work with differences and only convert them back to the original scale when you are all done. It makes the formulas simpler and the calculations less error-prone. Especially so once you start looking at second and higher differences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your argument about working with the differenced series , but I am using R for the forecast/calculations and also just the first difference of the series so it won't be much of a problem.